# Correct a menu hover display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a website in which I have a menu that opens a sub-menu while you hover it. But it has a little problem: the submenu is a few pixels under the menu item that displays it.

Here is the website:
https://www.redlineaviation.com/

The problem is when you hover **"What type of plane do you have?"** and you try to select an item, if you move your mouse fast then there's no problem, but if you move it a little slow then you'll see the problem.

Comment: Okey i got your problem .. post scripts that you use to achieve hover effect..

Comment: So the question is: do you want this gap or not?

Comment: `and the problem is when you hover What type of plane do you have? and you try to select an item, if you move your mouse fast then there's no problem, but if you move it a little slow then you find the problem.`use a hover delay for your problem or remove the gap between the two tabs

Comment: @dfsq No he wants time for that menu to stay..

Comment: A bit unrelated but your "contact us" link in the footer is out of place. Fix it, I am tearing my hair out.

Comment: I don't need the gap between the menu item and the sub-menu but i can't find why is that gap

Answer (score 1):

Since you show submenu on `:hover` you should take care of the gap between menu and submenu, because obviously when mouse cursor gets in the gap menu is no longer in `:hover` state and submenu hides. It's very easy to fix. Decrease `top` position a little to get rid of the gap, but make a visial "new" gap with padding-top:

```
.menu li:hover ul, .menu li.sfHover ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 28px;        /* make top smaller to remove the gap */
    z-index: 9;
    padding-top: 8px; /* and make gap again with padding-top */
}
```

UPD: As noted by @Paulie_D setting top position to `100%` makes more sense, no magic numbers. However padding-top is needed to make a nice space between menu and submenu. So combination of two answers make it ideal :)

Comment: +1 for the padding top although i prefer `top:100%`.

Comment: You are right, 100% is better so +1 for your idea too. Although I think padding-top is needed because when submenu sticks to menu without any space between, it's looks a little clumsy.

Comment: I agree...the padding is a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

The menu is positioned a fixed number of pixels below the parent `li`.

Because there is a slight gap, the hover state is removed when you 'hover' over the gap.

Just change the `top` position from the fixed value to 100%

```
.menu li:hover ul, .menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
top: 100%; /* always in place regardless of parent height */
z-index: 9;
}
```